# Why do I get invalid syntax assigning local variables AFTER an IF statement in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, variables, recursion

I'm going through this MIT Intro to Comp Sci Using Python course on Edx. There is an exercise telling us to use bisection search and recursion to **check if a character is in an alphabetically ordered string**. For some reason, I got a **syntax error when I put the variable HALF after that If-statement, while I won't get an error if I declare it before the If-statement**. All I could find is not being able to declare local variables in an If-statement. **Please tell me or refer me to websites explaining why this happens?** **Thanks a bunch.**

Here's the code:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    if len(aStr) <= 1 and char != aStr:
        return False

    HALF = len(aStr) // 2

    elif char == aStr[HALF]:
        return True 
    elif char < aStr[HALF]:
        return isIn(char, aStr[:HALF])
    else:
        return isIn(char, aStr[HALF:])
        
    
print(isIn('a', ''))
```

Comment: This is a simple indentation typo, or a glaring logic error.  Either way, the `HALF` line is invalid, inserted illegally into the middle of an if-elif-else sequence.  Retpeat your tutorial on the `if` statement to learn the legal forms.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Gotcha, it turns out that it was just a rule I haven't noticed. At first, I couldn't wrap my head around the idea. I just needed someone to tell me, "hey, your if-else sequence isn't used properly". Not a lot of documentations and tutorials point that out explicitly tho.

Comment: No, because the documentation and tutorials are concerned with showing you the extent of correct ways to do things -- they don't even *try* to exhibit all of the *wrong* ways.

Comment: K, thanks for reminding me of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get invalid syntax because Python, unlike other languages, utilizes space/tab to keep track of block of codes. A proper Python `if` statement (with `elif`) looks like so:

```py
a = 10

if a == 0:
    b = 10
elif a == 1:
    b = 100
else:
    b = 1000
```

`elif`, as you might expect, requires an `if` statement before it can be used. When you break the spacing:

```py
a = 10

if a == 0:
    b = 10

a = 1

elif a == 1:
    b = 100
else:
    b = 1000
```

Python does not know where `elif a == 1` is connected to, and thus gives you a syntax error. You likely meant:

```py
def isIn(char, aStr):
    if len(aStr) <= 1 and char != aStr:
        return False

    HALF = len(aStr) // 2

    # 'if', not 'elif' here.
    if char == aStr[HALF]:
        return True 
    elif char < aStr[HALF]:
        return isIn(char, aStr[:HALF])
    else:
        return isIn(char, aStr[HALF:])
        
    
print(isIn('a', ''))
```